# Writing Integration Test of a Django ListView

Tags: django, testing, integration

How to write an integration test of the following list view in django? I need an example.

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Donor
    template_name = 'recipient/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'donors'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if form:
            return Donor.objects.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=form) |
                Q(location__icontains=form) | 
                Q(sex__icontains=form) | 
                Q(age__icontains=form) | 
                Q(blood_group__icontains=form)
            ).order_by('id')
        queryset = Donor.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['q'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework provides a very convenient [test framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/).

In your test you would mock an API request to your endpoint and then check that the response of the request matches what you were expecting.

As an example. in your test you might want to create a few `Donor` instances to query, make the request and then see if the response contains the donors you were expecting. You can add filters to the request to test if they work for instance.